# Rotativa component throws error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1 while generating the pdf in MVC project

Tags: model-view-controller, pdf-generation, rotativa

I have used this component to generate a pdf document based out of a dynamic view content. On testing at DEV and Staging environment, it worked fine and on Production environment, it throws below shown error.

> Could not load file or assembly '**System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'** or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Rotativa Version: 1.0.0.0

System.Web.Mvc Version: 5.2.3.0

I have given the binding redirect in web.config as below.

*bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"*

**Code:**

```
var pdfLetter = new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf(viewName, viewModel);

pdfLetter.FileName = fileName;

pdfLetter.PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4;

pdfLetter.PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Portrait;

pdfLetter.PageMargins = new Rotativa.Options.Margins { Left = 4, Right = 1 };

var letterBytes = pdfLetter.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);

return letterBytes;
```

Web Application is not referencing the 3.0.0.1 version anywhere and still it throws the error. Tried to check the available Stack Overflow threads to fix.

Does anyone encountered this same problem and have any workaround to fix?

Comment: Update: After trying so much on this issue, it is observed that the website generates the pdf using rotativa when it is deployed outside of default web site(port 80). However this fails if it is under default website area...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was config value mismatch for MVC redirect between two environments and system was not able to recognize it. Fixed the issue by creating the web.config redirect section from the scratch.