# Rotativa viewaspdf works in dev, staging but throws error in prod

Tags: .net, pdf, model-view-controller, rotativa

I have integrated MVC (using Areas concept) into an existing web forms project to generate reports as pdf document using Rotativa component. Project framework is set to 4.5.1.

On testing at dev and staging environments it works fine but it fails at prod.
On prod, it throws the below error:

[Rotativa component throws error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1 while generating the pdf in MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564429/rotativa-component-throws-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-mvc)

Can we install System.Web.Mvc.dll (version 3.0.0.1) on prod environment to fix this issue?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ah, is this a repost of your previous question? Please don't duplicate questions here - it only creates clean-up work when it is spotted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotativa component throws error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1 while generating the pdf in MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564429/rotativa-component-throws-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-mvc)

Comment: got it .. will take care..is there any other way to get the attention and response in a faster way for this kind of urgent scenarios?

Comment: Not really, no. In the future, if you acquire some reputation points, you can add them as a bounty to a question. However, you need to wait for a question to be at least two days old in order to apply a bounty, so it would not help you in this case anyway.

Comment: Other than that, the only way to get attention on a question is to promote it (some people Tweet them or paste them to relevant social media). If you need priority treatment then I suggest you look for alternative sources of assistance. There are several (paid) websites to get quality freelancers, perhaps that is the best approach?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The question mentioned in the other link was posted two weeks before and couldn't able to get any response. The current thread specifically targets about the MVC dll deployment to GAC as workaround solution...

Comment: You could see if there is a Reddit sub for this platform. If you do repost this elsewhere on the web, make sure you edit each duplicate copy to point to all the others, so that if one of them gets answers in the long run, future readers can discover them. Note also that a question not getting answers in two weeks is not sufficient justification for duplication - the duplication still creates work for volunteer janitors.

Comment: Irrespective of portal account reputations, if there is a way to post a question and seek for a voluntary guidance on a emergency situation it would be helpful very much...

Comment: No, and there should not be. When you read my link in my first comment in its entirety (and I do hope you will), one of the things discussed in there is how much such a system would be open to abuse, and how much people would falsely claim they had an emergency when in fact they do not. I suggest you look at paying someone for support - see TopTal and AirPair etc.